# E-mail management question

Tags: email, time-management, software

There is an internal support type department in our company that gets bombarded with emails daily from staff.

The support group is 8 people, each part of the same email workgroup on MS Office.

Basically, a staff member will email this workgroup when a specific file needs to be actioned or maintained. Each person in the workgroup receives the mail, and basically they are answered first come first served, by whomever is available to respond. The person who responds then has to notify the workgroup that they've picked up the request so that it doesn't get worked on by multiple people. Obviously this creates even more email.

I've thought of suggesting a support ticket style system, however with the types of requests they receive, I'm not sure how it would work...

Is there another stratgey within MS outlook that can better organize these workgroup emails? I was hoping there was a way to color code them in a way visible to the group once they are actioned, but I don't think so...

Can anyone recommend a solution or  program that could handle daily incoming requests?

Comment: This is more of a question of productivity rather than the workplace.  It may be better to pose the question on http://productivity.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thans, I will try that

Comment: It sounds like you want a ticketing system with an email interface.

Comment: If you decide you *do* want a system, such a question might be on-topic at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: YOu can set up categories one for each person. THen when they grab that email, they assign it to their category. Or you can set up folders for each person inteh inbox and they coudl move the email to the folder when they have assigned it to themselves and move completed requests to another folder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to setup a ticket tracking system.

Comment: @IndigoJane Do you work at unnamed betting company? Because this sounds too similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira):
You can use https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira - set up the workflows to indicate what status the job is in. Assign it to the next person, or it can auto assign. It is normally used for software development teams. We are implementing it to manage logistics at our company. When something is assigned, nobody would pick it up by mistake. It has tons of email configuration options to auto send emails on certain triggers. For small companies it is cheap. Id recommend getting a pro to install/configure it. If you host it yourself, it will cost your company 10 dollars for the software. All you are looking for is workflow management system.

Comment: Jira (a stellar system) is strongly geared towards developers. A better suggestion would have been [Service Desk](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/service-desk) - a plugin for jira.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches that will work.  The simplest, given that you are using Outlook (and presumably Exchange behind it), is to [redirect the Support emails to a Public Folder](http://www.outlookwise.com/outlookwise/tips_tricks/exchange_server/configuring_a_public_folder_email_address.htm).

However, this requires a fair amount of internal discipline in handling received, in progress, and completed tasks.  Having said that there are 8 of you, and presumably working different shifts, I think that's a little unrealistic.  You're really just big enough to use a ticketing system.  Jira is great, as [crh225 said](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/49270/9264).  There are dozens out there.  I like [FreshDesk](http://freshdesk.com/) for my team, but that's because it has an integrated phone system, too.  This isn't the place to hash out all the merits and foibles of the different platforms out there.  Find two or three that you think would fit your group well, and take it to your manager.  Almost all of them will let you redirect emails into it to create tickets from your users' messages automatically.